# Oracle 12.1 Create text data from a select with a function

Tags: oracle, plsql

Okay, hello everyone. So my project is simple, but complex at the same time. I need to create a SQL procedure in my Oracle 12.1 database that will be called from an external client. With my limited knowledge of PLSQL, I made this code:

```
CREATE TYPE CC_DATA_RESPONSE is TABLE OF varchar2(1500);
CREATE FUNCTION getSearchResults(theSubject IN VARCHAR2, theTerm IN VARCHAR2)
   RETURN CC_DATA_RESPONSE
   IS
   theResults CC_DATA_RESPONSE;
BEGIN  
  SELECT DISTINCT column1, column2, column3
   BULK COLLECT INTO theResults
   FROM  myTable
   WHERE column1 > 1; 
        
   return theResults;
END;

BEGIN
 getSearchResults('BIO','202009');
END;
```

As you can see, I created a new type called CC_DATA_RESPONSE, that will be the final result type of my function. If you look into the SELECT, I use a BULK COLLECT INTO theResults (I am getting a warning there). Then, at the end, I return the variable theResults.

At the bottom, I have an extra block to call the function so I can test, but I get an error saying the getSearchResults is not declared... am I doing this right?

Other compilation errors

```
[Warning] ORA-24344: success with compilation error
[Warning] ORA-24344: success with compilation error
68/4    PL/SQL: ORA-00947: not enough values
6/3     PL/SQL: SQL Statement ignored
 (5: 0): Warning: compiled but with compilation errors
```

I know that for all you gurus out there these are simple and dumb questions... but, please help!!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`theResults` is of type `CC_DATA_RESPONSE` which is table of `VARCHAR2(1500)`.

It can hold all the data from one column from your table with `VARCHAR2` datatype in it.

The mistake that you are doing is here:

```
SELECT DISTINCT column1, column2, column3 -- 3 columns here
   BULK COLLECT INTO theResults -- but this can hold only one column's data
```

It should be either

```
SELECT DISTINCT column1 
   BULK COLLECT INTO theResults
```

or

```
SELECT DISTINCT column2
   BULK COLLECT INTO theResults
```

or

```
SELECT DISTINCT column3
   BULK COLLECT INTO theResults
```

Update:

Comma separated values:

```
SELECT DISTINCT column1 || ',' || column2 || ',' || column3
   BULK COLLECT INTO theResults
```

Comment: But, what if I want to collect the results into a single stream separated by commas or other format?

Comment: Got it. About the final part of my question: How to test it in Toad? I added a new begin/end block at the bottom but then I get this error: getSearchResults is not declared

Comment: While calling the function, declare one variable of type `CC_DATA_RESPONSE` and then assign this variable a function like ` your_variable := your_function(..)` in begin block